# Why all my loops don`t work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

http://jsfiddle.net/VaAlina/oupmd0hf/

Commented code don`t work.
Area next to bomb is green. Yellow - bombs. Blue - emptiness .

I want to replace this kind of code->

```
var dangerItem1 = "#" + danger1;//Replace thise code to commented
var dangerItem2 = "#" + danger2;
var dangerItem3 = "#" + danger3;
var dangerItem4 = "#" + danger4;
```

With this->

```
/*
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    var dangerItem+j = "#" + danger+j;
}
*/
```

Where is the mistake?

Comment: You can't declare variables names dynamically as you did in `var dangerItem + j`. But you could go with an array `var dangerItems = [];` and to push the elements inside

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically create a variable name.

What you could do though is store them in arrays or objects.

Objects can accept dynamic property names using `[]` notation.

```
var danger =['green','red','blue','pink'];
var dangerItem = [];

for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    dangerItem.push( "#" + danger[j]);
}
 // returns ["#green", "#red", "#blue", "#pink"] 

/* or */
var dangerItem = {};
for(var j = 0; j < 4; j++){
    dangerItem[ danger[j] ] =  "#" + danger[j];
} 
// returns {"green":"#green","red":"#red","blue":"#blue","pink":"#pink"}
```

Comment: You actually sort of can: `window['danger'+j]`—abusing JavaScript’s index notation to access object keys.

Comment: @Xufox not really abusing the notation and it is valid. I felt was better not to suggest polluting global namespace though for someone who seems to be just starting out

Comment: Yeah, of course…I kinda remembered from somewhere years ago that `window[…]` was bad practice. I didn’t clearly remember the reason though…